# Deploy Multiple Azure WebJobs to a Single Azure AppService in YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-webjobs-continuous

I'm trying to have a deployment pipeline that deploys 3 Azure WebJobs (continous) that are all part of the same solution at once. I can do this in Visual Studio by right click deploy and ensure I'm not clearing existing files.

In Azure Pipelines I have the following script that works successfully for a single WebJob Deployment.

However, if I duplicate it and create an new pipeline for my second WebJob, it will replace the existing WebJob, only leaving 1 running.

What do I modify in the below pipeline for it build/deploy all 3 WebJobs?

```
trigger: none
    
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    
    # Modify these variables
variables:
  webJobName: 'My.WebJob.App'
  azureAppServiceName: 'my-webjobs'
  azureSPNName: 'MyRGConnection' #get it from your AzureDevOps portal
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  dotNetFramework: 'net6.0'
  dotNetVersion: '6.0.x'
  targetRuntime: 'win-x86'

# Build the app for .NET 6 framework  https://www.tiffanychen.dev/Azure-WebJob-Deployments-YAML/
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: $(dotNetVersion)
    includePreviewVersions: true
  displayName: 'Build .NET 6 Application'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --framework $(dotNetFramework) --runtime $(targetRuntime) --self-contained --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebJob/App_Data/jobs/continuous/$(webJobName)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    projects: '$(webJobName)/$(webJobName).csproj'

# Package the file and uploads them as an artifact of the build

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Generate run.cmd For WebJob
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '"dotnet $(WebJobName).dll" | Out-File run.cmd -Encoding ASCII; $LASTEXITCODE'
    pwsh: true
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebJob/App_Data/jobs/continuous/$(webJobName)'
        
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: Zip Desired Files
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebJob/'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(webJobName).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish All Artifacts
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifact'
  inputs:
    path: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSPNName) #this is the name of the SPN
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: $(azureAppServiceName) #App Service's unique name
    package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(webJobName).zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

Answer (score -2):

Variables give you a convenient way to get key bits of data into various parts of the pipeline. The issue is due to the hard coded values in the pipeline. As a result whenever we are running the pipeline, always same WebJob gets deployed.

The way to solve this problem is by replacing the hardcoded values by Pipeline variables as shown below.

```yaml
webJobName: $(webJobName)
azureAppServiceName: $(azureAppServiceName)
azureSPNName: $(azureSPNName)
```

We need to create pipeline variables and assign the values. Before running the .yml pipeline, variable need to be assigned with desired values for the WebJob.

You can check this [Define Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml,batch) document for more information.

You can also check this [Variable Group for Azure Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) document.

Comment: I am using variables I don't see how this is relevant to my issue.

Comment: Task AzureWebApp@1 - deploy one web app. If other two web app are going to make use of the same artifacts as above, we can deploy AzureWebApp@2 and AzureWebApp@3 in the same .yml file with different variable value for it.

Comment: i thought the @ sign was the version